# Using axios to delete the row from mysql db.React as front end with node.js and express.js as backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to delete the row from mysql database using axios and React.js as front end and node.js and express.js as backend. When i click the delete button the two request as send. One which shows nothing , and other which throws this in DevTools.

> "Cannot DELETE /employees"

Also it does not show any `console.log` statements in terminal.

Below is the code for route which has the problem in delete route

```
          const express = require("express");
      const app = express();
      const cors = require("cors");
      const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
      const logger = require("morgan");
      const port = process.env.PORT || 3301;
      var mysql = require("mysql");
      app.use(cors());
      const SELECT_ALL_USER_QUERY = 'SELECT * FROM employees';
      const DELETE_QUERY = 'Delete from employees where id =';
    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
      host: 'localhost',
      user:'root',
      password:"password",
      database:'People'
    });
    con.connect(function (err){
      if(err) {
        console.log("Error Conneting To DB",err)
      } else {
        console.log("Connection Established");
      }
    });

    //get Requets

    app.get('/employees', (req, res) => {
        con.query(SELECT_ALL_USER_QUERY, (err, result) => {
            if(err) {
                res.send(err);
            } else {
              let obj ={
                data : result
              }
              console.log(obj);
              res.send(result);
            }
        })
    });

    //Post Request
    app.post('/employees',(req,resp)=>{

      let data = {name:req.body.name , surname:req.body.surname, id:req.body.id};
      let sql_query = "INSERT INTO employees SET ?"
      console.log("DAATA UPLOADED")
      let query = con.query(sql_query,data,(err,resp)=>{
        if(err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
    });
    });

    //Delete Request

    // app.delete('/employees',(req,resp)=>{
    //   // DEBUG:
    //   let data = {id:req.body.id};
    //   let sql_query = "Delete from employees where id = ?"
    //   let query = con.query(sql_query,data,(err,resp)=>{
    //     if(err){
    //       console.log(err);
    //     }
    //     else {
    //       console.log(resp);
    //     }
    //   })
    // })
    // app.delete('/employees', function(req, res){
    //   console.log(con.query('DELETE FROM employees WHERE id =' + req.body.id));
    //   //con.query('DELETE FROM employees WHERE id ='+req.body.id, function(err, results){
    //     // if(err) throw err;
    //   // });
    //
    //   // req.flash('success', 'Project Deleted');
    //   // res.location('/admin');
    //   // res.redirect('/admin');
    //  });

    app.delete("/employees/:id", (req, res) => {
      console.log("Request",req.params.id);
      let { ID } = req.params.id;
      let sql = `DELETE FROM employees WHERE ID = ${req.params.id}`;
      console.log("HI",sql);


      // delete a row with id = req.params.id
      conn.query(sql, (error, results, fields) => {
        if (error) return console.error("ERROR HI",error.message);
        res.status(200).send(results);
        console.log("Deleted Row(s):", results.affectedRows);
      });
    });


    app.listen(4000, () => {
        console.log('server running on port 4000')
    })
    module.exports = app;
```

For ReactJs there is a function `deleteName` in which the call for delete using axios is written. Code is below:

```
      import React from 'react';
        import './App.css';
        import axios from 'axios';

        class App extends React.Component {
            constructor(props){
              super(props);
              this.onNameChange = this.onNameChange.bind(this);
              this.onSurnameChange = this.onSurnameChange.bind(this);
              this.onIdChange = this.onIdChange.bind(this);
              this.editName = this.editName.bind(this);
            this.state = {
              data:'',
              name:'',
              surname:'',
              id:''
            }
        }

        componentDidMount() {
          axios.get('http://localhost:4000/employees').then((response,err)=> {
            if(err) {
              console.log('err');
            }
            this.setState((prevstate) =>
              ({
              data: response.data
              })
            );
          })
        }
        handleSumbit(e){
        axios.post('http://localhost:4000/employees',{
            name: this.state.name,
            surname: this.state.surname,
            id:this.state.id,
          }).then((response,err)=>{
          if(err) {
            console.log("Error While Posting Data",err);
          }
        console.log("RESPONSE FROM POST",response);
        })
        }
        onNameChange(e){
          this.setState({
            name:e.target.value
          });
        }
        onSurnameChange(e) {

        this.setState({
          surname:e.target.value
        })

        }
        onIdChange(e){
          this.setState({
            id:e.target.value
          });
        }
        editName(e,firstname,lastname,id){
          this.setState({
            name:firstname,
            surname:lastname,
            id:id
          });
        }
        deleteName(e,value) {


         axios.delete('http://localhost:4000/delete/' + value).then((response) => {
      // this only runs on success
      console.log("RESPONSE FROM POST", response.data);
    }, (err) => {
      // this only runs on error
      console.log("Error While Posting Data", err);
    });

}
        }


        render() {
      const {data} = this.state;
      return (
    <div className="container">
      <div>
        <label className="">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="" value={this.state.name} onChange={(e)=>this.onNameChange(e)}/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label className="">Surname</label>
        <input type="text" name="" value={this.state.surname} onChange={(e)=>this.onSurnameChange(e)}/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label className=""> YOUR ID </label>
        <input type="number" name="" value={this.state.id} onChange={(e)=>this.onIdChange(e)}/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={(e)=> this.handleSumbit(e)}>Sumbit</button>
      </div>

        <div className="main-container">
        <h1>Name</h1>
        {
        data && data.map((data,key) => {
          return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className="child">
                    {data.name}
                    <button onClick={(e)=> this.editName(e,data.name,data.surname,data.id)}>Edit</button>
                    <button onClick={(e)=> this.deleteName(e,data.id)}>Delete</button>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
          )
        })
      }
      </div>
    </div>
    )

        }

      }

    export default App;
```

Comment: You're sending the request to a route called ```/employees```, but the back end is handing a route called ```/delete/:id```. You'd need to change the route in one of those places

Answer (score 0):

The error "Cannot DELETE /employees" means that a route named `/employees` does not exist. You need to make the call to the route `/delete/:id`.

On another note, I noticed you were not handling the error properly in axios. The `.then` function takes two callbacks, the first is executed on success, and the other on error.

In total, those two things combined, try doing it like this:

```
axios.delete('http://localhost:4000/delete/' + value).then((response) => {
  // this only runs on success
  console.log("RESPONSE FROM POST", response.data);
}, (err) => {
  // this only runs on error
  console.log("Error While Posting Data", err);
});
```

Comment: When i made the call to `/delete/:id` then it says ` Cannot DELETE /employees/678`

Comment: @SAMAR That doesn't make any sense. If you're making the request to `/delete/678` then there's no possible way you would get that error. There may be some other important code you are not showing us.

Comment: @SAMAR Edit your question and put it in there, code does not format properly in comments. From what I can see here though the route name is fine. The front-end must still be sending the request to `/employees` somehow. The error `Cannot DELETE /employees/678` literally means "you tried to call the route /employees/678 but it does not exist". So the front-end is still calling the wrong URL.

Comment: updated my code in question.Request you to have a look.

Comment: @SAMAR Actually from reading the React code a little deeper, it looks like you are calling the `GET /employees` route, and that is actually where the error is thrown. Not on delete. Does there exist a route named `/employees`?

Comment: Yes there exist the route name employees which is used to get request and post request. There are two routes named `/employee`.

Comment: @SAMAR Well, the error is saying that it doesn't exist so there's something funky with your server config where that route may not be hooked up properly. You may have defined it but not hooked it into the main router or something like that. But I can say for sure, the `/delete/:id` is not what is causing the error. It's your call to `/employees`.

Comment: I finally found out that my connection obect named was con. I was using it as conn.And also i did correction in your first code and added this
` axios.delete('http://localhost:4000/employees/' + value).then((response)`. It is working now. Thanks for your support.